# Python: How to override a memory at a pointer location?

Tags: python, memory

Given the following code

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self._foo = foo

a = Test("bar") # id(a) returns e.g. 2243221358240
b = Test("rab") # id(b) returns e.g. 2243221358184
```

I want to copy the object being referenced by `b` to the location of `a` such that `id(a)` still returns the orignal address, but `a._foo` returns `rab`.

What is the "pythonic" way to do so?
Is this possible in Python at all?

Comment: This seems like an xy problem, why do you want to do such thing ?

Comment: Consider e.g. a singly linked list, where you only have access to a middle node that you want to delete.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this. Its normal for containers, though. If `a` is a list, you can change its members. If `Test` is your own class, you could define a method that reassigns everything.

Comment: `a._foo = b._foo`

Comment: @boen - interesting case. There, you could have a standard header and you'd just replace the contained object.

Comment: @kindall that only copies the value of one attribute, and not the whole object, which is what I'm asking for.

Comment: @Boern **+1** for the **XLR-Stecker** as aGrillspieß-API connector **:o)**

Comment: In Cpython, Id is frequently a memory address to a python object header. Different data types have different length headers. You could only "save" the ID by copying headers. If its a large header over a small one, you've just corrupted memory.

Comment: I'm basically looking for the Python equivalent to the C++ `memcpy( dst, src, sizeof(dst) )`

Comment: Assuming both objects have `__dict__` attributes, which should be true of most user-defined objects (but not necessarily built-in ones), you could use `a.__dict__.update(b.__dict__)`.

Comment: `memcpy` is a C function and generally can't handle anything beyond simple references to C++ objects. I'm not sure what would happen to a `std::vector` for instance.

Comment: Interesting, like an reflection-ish property. I see that's already proposed, but downvoted ?

Comment: You can't copy dicts in general. It will work when you are only doing it to same-class objects where the internal state of the object doesn't cause problems. But that's fragile code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python isn't C and it doesn't make sense to talk about copying one instance's memory on top of another's. You can achieve a similar result by copying all the attributes from one instance to another.

In most Python objects, the attributes are stored in an instance attribute called `__dict__`, except when there's a `__slots__` attribute on the class, which defines the names of the allowed attributes.

Many built-in Python objects are implemented in C and so don't have either of these attributes. These generally can't be copied by attribute in any sensible automated fashion.

With these caveats, you could do something like the following:

```
def copy_attributes(obj1, obj2):
    if not isinstance(obj1, type(obj2)) and not isinstance(obj2, type(obj1)):
        raise TypeError("source and target object types must be related somehow")
    # fast path if both have __dict__
    if hasattr(obj1, "__dict__") and hasattr(obj2, "__dict__"):
        obj2.__dict__.update(obj1.__dict__)
        return
    # copy one attribute at a time
    names = getattr(type(obj1), "__slots__", ()) and getattr(obj1, "__dict__", ())
    slots = set(getattr(type(obj2), "__slots__", ()))
    if slots and not all(name in slots for name in names):
        raise AttributeError("target lacks a slot for an attribute from source")
    for name in names:
        setattr(obj2, getattr(obj1, name))
```

The way I've written this function, the two instances must be related (one a subclass of the other's type). This increases the likelihood that this will actually work, although depending on how the classes are set up, it may or may not result in a useful configuration of `obj2` unless they are exactly the same type. That is, attributes that `obj2` has but `obj1` doesn't will retain their original values, and this may produce an inconsistent object. You might prefer more strict type-checking: `if type(obj1) is not type(obj2)` for example.

if the type of `obj2` has `__slots__` and `obj1` has attributes that aren't permitted in `obj2`, you'll get an error trying to set those attributes. In this case, I check to make sure all the attributes about to be copied exist in `__slots__`. Otherwise you could end up without all attributes copied.

You could remove some or all of these safety checks for performance reasons, if you know the types you'll be using.

Note that attributes defined on the class, including methods, aren't copied by this function; it copies instance attributes only. The copies are shallow, so mutable objects are shared. You can add `copy.copy` or `copy.deepcopy` calls if this is important.